# Python __setitem__ rhs operand can't infer type of lambda?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, pylance

Pylance gives the following error for this given code:

```
Cannot access member "foo" for type "object*"
  Member "foo" is unknown Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

class Test:
    foo: int

T = TypeVar("T")

class TestClass:
    def __setitem__(self, key: type[T], value: Callable[[T], int]) -> None:
        ...
    def add(self, key: type[T], value: Callable[[T], int]) -> None:
        ...

a = TestClass()
a[Test] = lambda x: x.foo # Can't figure out type(x)?
a.add(Test, lambda x: x.foo) # Works, knows that type(x) is Test

def blah(x: Test) -> int:
    return x.foo
a[Test] = blah # works (correct)

def blah_fail(x: Test) -> str:
    return str(x)
a[Test] = blah_fail # fails (correct)
a[Test] = "asd" # fails (correct)
```

Why does the type system not know that the lambda's parameter is a Test, yet it works for a similar function add()?

Comment: `mypy` works as expected here ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=57a965d6a5f227ed89dcc82b55e113cf)), so it's a pyright bug. Consider reporting at their [issues tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright), Eric Traut (main maintainer) usually responds very quickly.